# Android ListView multichoice mode automatically closed after release long press in list child item

Tags: android, listview, modal-dialog

I have list view enabled multi choice modal mode enabled; everything works fine if I long press the list item.

Failure case: 
* Have one child item with image and it has its own OnClick and OnLongClick. 
* I implemented long click listener to activate action mode of listview that method implementation is below; Just assume the position as 5 for list item size is 7

```
int position = 5;
ListView list = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).myList;
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //TODO view image
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Logger.info("Item selection called via Media long click");
        final boolean value = !list.isItemChecked(position);
        list.setItemChecked(position, value);
        return true;
    }
```

OnLong click it selected the list view and on releasing touch (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) automatically the list selection is cleared and the action mode is disabled.

Note: It works fine for the list item long click directly; Failed only for specific child item click!

[image: Longpress]

Comment: hi, I am facing the same problem. can you tell me how did you solved it?

Comment: Implement two way touch listener for view in viewholder and listview, then using our custom flags either boolean or item position according to our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the click events of imageView and TextView (in listView) and enable the click event of the parent. Then on the click of parent switch the flag value to check or uncheck the item and notify the listview using notifyDatasetchange() method.

Hope this helps

Anurag

Comment: Thanks Anurag, But I need some more clarification; Its clear but I need click event on that image view; So I have both click and long click on that. And the touch listener for the list for double tap; Even that I made clear log for all the listeners. No other events affecting this long click. The release of long click on that image itself enables the list selector. So it show selected on pressed state and on release the selection is cleared.